# Comparing two sets of numbers

Tags: python, set, python-2.x

I am trying to compare two sets for matching numbers. The once a number has been found append the username associated with the numbers to a dictionary along with the amount of numbers they have matched. My explanation is not the best but perhaps my code will show what I am trying to do.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE drawnumber = (%s)'.format(numbertable),
          drawnumber)
numbers = c.fetchall()[0]
print(numbers)

numbers = set(imap(str.rstrip, numbers))

print(numbers)

c.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE paid = (%s)'.format(table), paid)
entries = c.fetchall()
print(entries)

results = defaultdict(list)

for row in entries:
    user = row[1]
    number1 = row[2]
    number2 = row[3]
    number3 = row[4]
    number4 = row[5]
    number5 = row[6]
    pub_key = row[7]

    results[sum(n in numbers for n in row)].append(user)
```

FYI: the set numbers looks like so: `set(['11', '12', '15', '1', '3', '8'])`

The entries set looks something like this:

```
((9L, 'test8', 12L, 4L, 3L, 15L, 8L, '1Bu1hXvk7NzoCgRFyXcGwFULtdSRsDNoCy', 'T'),
 (10L, 'test9', 12L, 4L, 1L, 15L, 8L, '1Bu1hXvk7NzoCgRFyXcGwFULtdSRsDNoCy', 'T'))
```

Comment: The numbers set contains strings, not numbers. Not sure if that's what you wanted because you'll have to cast them back to ints to compare.

Comment: Which number or numbers from the `entries` results do you want to compare against your `set`? What is your desired results for the example data you've shown?

Comment: Hi so in the case of the user "test8" I would like to compare his number 12, 4, 3, 15, 8. With the set. It would be cool if I could then append the username to a dict. With the key perhaps containing how many number they have matched.

Comment: just as a timesaver: `for _, user, number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, pub_key in entries:` works too. You might have to do `...pub_key, *_` if there are more than 8 fields

Comment: @AdamSmith Awesome thanks

Comment: @erip really? He's using parameterization in some places and not others. I'm assuming `numbertable` and `table` aren't user-entered, so they're not part of the threat vector for sql injection.

Comment: @AdamSmith correct they are not user entered so no sql injection worries.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `set.intersection`

```
for _, user, number1, number2, number3, number4, \
        number5, pub_key, _ in row:
    row_nums = set([number1, number2, number3, number4, number5])
    matching = row_nums.intersection(numbers)
    if matching:
        results[len(matching)].append(user)
```

However `numbers` is a set of strings, not a set of ints. You should fix that.

```
numbers = set(imap(int, imap(str.rstrip, numbers)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am getting the error: `'long' object is not iterable
`

Comment: Not sure unpacking is necessary , `for t in row:  mat = numbers.intersection(t)`, no need to make a second set

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'd be concerned with not unpacking, since we're not looking for matches in the first or last column. The first column is also of type `long`, so I'd be worried about false matches there.

Comment: @Joshua is `row` always what you think it is? That error sounds like `row` is a `long`. Nothing else here iterates.

Comment: The OP has `sum(n in numbers for n in row)` in their own code so not sure what they are including, another issue is if numbers can repeat in the row, summing and getting the intersection will yield different results in that case

Comment: @PadraicCunningham true! Worth considering, but I think `set.intersection` should be preferred unless there's a strong reason not to use it.

Comment: @AdamSmith I left out some info from the mysql query to make the code I post here less messy. They are also not relevant to what I am trying to do here. I believe I have evaded those columns however by doing `for _, user, number1, number2, number3, number4, number5, pub_key, _, _, _ in row:`

Comment: Another note the numbers cant repeat in the row. The first mysql value in an id not a user entered number. So the numbers selected are all unique

Comment: If you're going to `map` (or `imap`) the `int` constructor over your list of "number" strings, you don't need to `rstrip` them first. `int` will ignore any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Joshua might be better at this point to do `for line in row: user, row_numbers, pub_key = row[1], row[2:7], row[7]`! That's getting REALLY long, and since you don't really care about the numbers individually, this lets you just toss them all together.